# hbase as database in web application

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata

A big question about using hadoop or related technologies in a real web application.

I just want to find out how a web app can use hbase as its database. I mean is it the thing the big data apps do or they use normal databases and just use these sort of technologies for analysis?

Is it ok to have a online store with Hbase database or something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly fine to have hbase as your backend. 
What I am doing to get this done,( I have a online community and forum running on my website )

1.Writing C# code to access the Hbase using thrift, very easy and simple to get this done. (Thrift is a cross language binding    platform, to HBase Java is only the first class citizen!)

2.Managing   the HBase cluster(have it on Amazon) using the Amazon EMI

3.Using ganglia to monitor Hbase

Some Extra tips:

So you can organize the web application like this

1. You can set up your webservers on Amazon Web Services or IBMWebSphere
2. You can set up your own HBase cluster using cloudera or use AmazonEC2 again here.
3. Communication between web server and Hbase master node happens via thrift client.
4. You can generate thrift code in your own desired programming language
   Here are some links that helped me 
   A)[Thrift Client](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/thrift/doc-files/Hbase.html#Fn_Hbase_getRowWithColumns),
   B)[Filtering options](http://hbase.apache.org/book/thrift.html)

Along with this I refer to HBase administrative cookbook by Yifeng Jiang and HBase reference guide by Lars George in case I dont get answers on web.

Filtering options provided by HBase are fast and accurate. Let's say if you use HBase for storing your product details, you can have sub-stores and have a column in your Product table, which tells to which store a product may belong and use Filters to get products for a specific store.

Comment: very nice, so you did, what I want to do. You have real web app which does crud operations on hbase. that's what i was looking for. could you please give its link?

Comment: I am sorry the website is available to subscribers only. Also I did not use CloudEra or HortonWorks, used AWS wherever possible. For now you can check the edit to the existing answer to find out what can be done.

Comment: well. I will ask for help, when I start my project. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the article below:

"Apache HBase Do’s and Don’ts"

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/04/hbase-dos-and-donts/

Comment: that is a great article and helped a lot. but the question is still there, can or better to say, should i use these sort of technologies to develop a for example online store? I think not, so how can i use for example mahout for recommendation or things like these.